# Pause for loop and wait for user key press every 'n' iterations. - Python

Tags: python, loops, enumeration

I have for loop which looks like this:

```
for trial in trials:
    stim.text = trial[0]
    stim.color = trial[1]
    win.flip()
    isi = random.random() * 2.0
    core.wait(isi)
    stim.draw()
    event.clearEvents()
    displaytime = win.flip()
    keys = event.waitKeys(keyList=answer_keys.keys(), timeStamped=True)
    rt =  keys[0][1] - displaytime
    trialNum +=1
    if trial[0] == trial[1]:
        condition = 'congruent'
    elif trial[0] != trial[1]:
        condition = 'incongruent'
    logfile.write('{},{},{},{},{},{:.3f}\n'.format(trialNum, trial[0], trial[1], condition, keys[0], rt))
```

what I want to do is pause the for loop at a given number of iterations and wait for the users key press to continue.

So if I supplied the value 5 this would pause the loop every 5 iterations.

Anymore questions or info required let me know. All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `input` built-n function at your desired number of iterations:

```
input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

let's say that you want at `n` iterations to make the pause:

```
n = 7

for i in range(1, 20):
    if i % n == 0:
        input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

if you iterate over a list with different kind of elements:

```
for i, e in enumerate(my_list):
    if i % n == 0:
        input("Press Enter to continue...")
    ... other code...
```

Comment: Yes... what I would like to know is how to present that on a given number of iterations. The problem I am having is with supplying the loop the number of iterations to pause at.